# Two entries printing the same thing when you click on the different buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new at using Tkinter I tried to search up the answer but, I just got much more confused. whenever I try to run the the program and print out the two entries by pressing the two buttons, it will only print out the second entry and ignore the first. Each of the two buttons still append in their proper list but, just append the same thing, the second entry.

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 125
WIDTH = 600

the_text_holder = []
the_date_holder = []


def get_text(entry):
  the_text_holder.append(entry)
  print(the_text_holder)

def get_date(entry):
    the_date_holder.append(entry)
    print(the_date_holder)


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()



frame = tk.Frame(root, bg= "#696969")
frame.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)



label = tk.Label(frame,text= "Reminder", bg = "#696969", font = ("arial", 12))
label.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.01)

label = tk.Label(frame,text= "Enter reminder:", bg = "#21558c", font = ("arial", 12))
label.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.19)

label = tk.Label(frame,text= "Enter time:", bg = "#21558c", font = ("arial", 12))
label.place(relx = 0.05, rely = 0.37)



entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg = "white")
entry.place(relx = 0.3, rely=0.19, relwidth = 0.6)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg = "white")
entry.place(relx = 0.3, rely=0.37, relwidth = 0.6)



button = tk.Button(frame, text ="Set text",bg = "#8b0000", command = lambda: get_text(entry.get()))
button.place(relx = 0.91, rely = 0.15)

button = tk.Button(frame, text ="Set time",bg = "#8b0000", command = lambda: get_date(entry.get()))
button.place(relx = 0.91, rely = 0.37)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign `entry` a new value, you need to rename the second `entry`

beware that you do the same with the `button` aswell...

```
reminder_entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
reminder_entry.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.19, relwidth=0.6)

time_entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
time_entry.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.37, relwidth=0.6)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Set text", bg="#8b0000", command=lambda: get_text(reminder_entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.91, rely=0.15)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Set time", bg="#8b0000", command=lambda: get_date(time_entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.91, rely=0.37)

root.mainloop()
```